# How should one spell the sound "eye" when creating a word?

Tags: pronunciation-respelling

How can I invent a word (or name) containing the sound "ai" (sounds like "eye") so that an English-speaker is likely to guess the correct pronunciation based on spelling alone, with no outside prompting?

For instance, if I wanted to create a spelling for a word to be pronounced like "eye's eye", how should I do this?

I've found partial solutions, but I find the limitations unacceptable.

Words like "pie", "ice", and "life" use a mechanism which only functions correctly near the end of a word. Worse, it sometimes fails entirely in longer words ("malice", "solstice", "hospice", "granite"). Trying to construct a spelling for my example word, we might come up with "Iezie" or "Izeie". These spellings seem to convey ambiguous pronunciation.

Words like "highlight" and "flight" provide something consistent, but this leads to awkward spellings. Consider "Ighzigh". A reader has some chance of settling on the correct pronunciation, but only after a period of mouthing nonsense while staring confused at that distracting Lovecraftian thing.

Words like "psychology" and "rely" require their pronunciation to be memorized. Otherwise, we might have a lot more fun pronouncing "physics". "Yzy" may look nice, but I would initially pronounce it like "easy", and do so with confidence.

I've also considered using "ai" to convey this, but it appears to function as I desire only when it ends a word. "Aizai" has a decent appearance, but it seems to suggest an English pronunciation like "A's eye".

And finally, "island", "wild", "rival", "chiral", and "chitin" appear to provide no guidance at all, and probably need to be memorized by rote. Each of these words is fun to say and looks good on a page, but only after some research.

Is there a compact, aesthetically-appealing solution?

Comment: If you have some idea what the word would sound like, or what it would mean, there might be information. But in general, @sumelic puts it perfectly.

Comment: most people know how to intuitively pronounce *bonzai*, which has the ending you're looking for.  thus, **aizai**.  i think the ending teaches the reader how to pronounce the beginning.

Comment: ***Aye***, captain! There's many ways to make the *igh* sound.

Comment: When George Lucas invented the name *Jedi*, how many Americans could pronounce it correctly when they simply saw it in print?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronunciation_respelling_for_English#Traditional_respelling_systems), we see that a variety of pronunciation respellings have been used in English, but this sound has no consistent representation.

Following English conventions, the sound is usually represented as *-ye* or *-ie*, or *eye* when it is a syllable on its own. However, these representations only really work when syllables are separated by something like a hyphen. So, "**eye-zye**". Although this is fairly effective at indicating the pronunciation of the term, it is probably not what you want.

However, another common representation that many English speakers are familiar with is "ai", as you note; it occurs in Spanish and the romanization of Japanese, two writing systems that English speakers are likely to be familiar with. This is ambiguous with the /eɪ/ pronunciation of *ai* in ordinary English words, but the English digraph *ai* does not occur at the end of words, while it does occur in Japanese loanwords like *samurai*. Therefore, I'd think most English speakers would associate this spelling with the pronunciation you desire when it's at the end of a word.

If people can tell that your writing system for words like this is consistent, they will then be able to infer that *ai* represents the sound of "eye" in other positions as well. The spelling "**aizai**" will then be relatively unambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

The old 50s rules for US English pronunciation hold that an "open" (vs "closed") syllable yields a "long" vowel sound.  A long I is pronounced "eye", and a short I is pronounced (roughly) "ih".

An open syllable is one that ends with the vowel, or one that ends with a consonant and the letter "E".

Even though these rules are (apparently) no longer taught, they are somewhat intuitive, so there's a good chance that they will be followed.

Comment: Yes; one example I can think of for a fictional character is the one named "Iroh" /ˈaɪroʊ/ ("EYE-roh") in the Nickelodeon cartoon series "Avatar: the Last Airbender". But clearly not all speakers find this pronunciation intuitive for this spelling, since in the live-action movie the name was apparently pronounced "EE-roh", to the displeasure of many of the fans of the cartoon.

Answer (score 1):

To make models of *lie*, *die*, *pie* is a very bad idea, because those spellings are exceptional, part of padding short ordinary words to at least three letters, as also *ebb*, *inn*, *lye*, *dye*, lest they be as short as special words *in*, *by*, *do*, *if*, … (and *go* is exception to exception—isn't English spelling great?). The usual spelling for that sound at that point is as in *spy*, *reply*, … (which, *sigh*, is changed to *ie* when *s* or *d* is added).
It is better to consider *field* or *sweetie* models for *ie*.
In your case, in spite of *ready*, …, I would use *y*, although, as you said, only *igh* is consistent.

The actual long-short spelling rule applys (!) only to some words, generally not to foreign ones, although there are native exceptions, too (*linen*):
When one of the five vowel letters is followed by one consonant letter, and maybe *l* or *r*, and a vowel letter or *y*, then the first vowel letter stands for a long vowel (diphthong). If one of the five vowel letters is followed by a consonant cluster other than final *nd* or *ld*, or the vowel-letter-following consonant is final, the vowel letter stands for a short vowel (monophthong).
This leaves out many cases: *liable*, *briar* (the *a* probably because *ie* is a digraph), *alkali*, the three-letter exceptions, *oboe*, *potatoes*, …. In general, in longer words, when final *e* is silent, *a* is schwa, *o* and *i* are long (but nowadays, mostly in invented names, there are many cases where final *i* is like *ie*), and *u* is found only in newish words (there is a completely arbitrary spelling rule that neither *v* nor *u* is final) and usually pronounced not long-*u*, but *oo*.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a fairly hopeless cause. It's not a fault of English - it's a feature!  You might be trying for something too clever.  Perhaps it's worth asking whether your really *need* your word to be pronounced consistently? As long as it's not rude or something.